# Django set value to POST form

Tags: python, django, html

My `views.py` looks like that

```
def add_note(request):

registered = False
user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.get_username())
if request.method == 'POST':
    note_form = NoteForm(data=request.POST)
    if note_form.is_valid():
        note = note_form.save()
        note.save()
        registered = True
    else:
         print(note_form.errors)

else:
    pass

return render(request, 'note.html', {'note_form': NoteForm, 'registered': registered})
```

In my `HTML` i use `<td><input type="datetime-local"  id="id_data" name="data" ></td>`

Data from this input is not valid because format is `2015-12-20T12:15`, should be `2015-12-20 12:15`

My question is:

1. It is possible to change data format in input? I need format like this `2015-12-20 12:15` (`T` switch to `SPACE`)
2. if not how change value of  `Data` in `views.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify what format does your datetime field accept from the form field in `NoteForm`, so that you can accept the default format:

```
data = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M'])
```

If you insist on using your desired format, you might need to change your front end `input` to somehow have the format.

Comment: It's strange for me becouse in database `T` is skipped and stay only `SPACE`

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comment, in what situation does it skip `T`? If your form is not valid how can you save data?

Comment: I add `data = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M'])` to `forms.py` and now form is valid. In database column with date do not contain `T`. You solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change the date format in your views usign embed python date functions. For example, you can use **strptime** and **strftime**, both datetime fuctions.

```
import datetime

new_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('07/12/2015', '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

strptime receives your request date, and strftime convert that date to a custom format.

Comment: Can you show me how use this in my `add_note` becouse i do not know how take date from form